# Sending files for signing and receive after signing DocuSIgn

Tags: php, signing, docusignapi

We are developing a web app in PHP.  What we require is that: An document has to be send for signing to docusign from our application and then once signed it should returned back to web  application. Process similar to Payment Gateway

Can it be done? How to do it? Where can I find the api integration module describing the process.

Comment: you'd better find a freelancer for that

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you describe is easily achievable using the DocuSign API (either REST or SOAP).  You should check out the DocuSign Developer Center, as it contains the information and resources you'll need to do this:  http://www.docusign.com/developer-center.  Starting with the "Quick Start" section of the DocuSign Developer Center probably makes most sense, given that the DocuSign API is entirely new for you. Good luck!

Comment: +1 You definitely want to start with the Quick Start guide of the DocuSign Dev Center as Kim has mentioned.  It leads to this [sample PHP code gist](https://gist.github.com/Ergin008/5484978#file-devcenter_quickstart-php) which you can enter your credentials in and run and it will send a signature request to your account's email address.